# Volume of liquid needed to fill sphere to height $h$

Tags: calculus

Find the volume of liquid needed to fill a sphere of radius $R$ to height $h$.

The picture shows $h$ up to maybe a quarter, I am not sure it seems pretty ambiguous.

No clue what to do here. I just know that the formula I am suppose to memorize is

$$V = \int \pi(R^2 - x^2)$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*In this answer, I'm not really going to explain how to fit the formula; rather, I'm giving a process that will work for nearly any type of Calc II "application" problem.*

The first step in any word problem is to **draw a picture** (even if you're given one--it still helps for you to draw your own.):

[image: Sphere]

Now, we can turn the drawing into an integral.  If we were to use discrete "slices" of the sphere to compute the volume, we'd have the following:  (Let $r(z)$ be the radius of a slice at a given height $z$, and $\Delta z$ be the height of a given slice.)
$$\sum \left(\pi\cdot\big(r(z)\big)^2\cdot\Delta z\right)$$

This is just summing up the volume of a bunch of really short cylinders.  As $\Delta z \to 0$, we have an integral:

$$\int_0^h\pi\cdot\big(r(z)\big)^2\;\mathrm dz$$

Now, what is $r(z)$?  Well, let's look at a circle of radius $R$, and see what its radius is as a function of $z$:

[image: Semicirc]

So, we see that $y = r(z) = \sqrt{R^2 - (z-R)^2}$.  Let's plug this into our integral we have above:

$$\int_0^h\pi\left(\sqrt{R^2 - (z-R)^2}\right)^2\;\mathrm dz$$
$$\int_0^h\pi(R^2 - (z-R)^2)\;\mathrm dz$$

The above integral gives the volume of the water in a sphere, filled to height $h$.

---

**Note:** my answer differs from the other answers because I positioned my sphere with the bottom at the origin, rather than centered at the origin.  In hindsight, the other way is simpler, but I didn't want to have to redo all my graphics. `:)`  To show they're the same, we perform the subsitution: 
$$u = z-R\implies \mathrm du = \mathrm dz$$
This implies:
$$\int_{-R}^{h-R}\pi(R^2 - u^2)\;\mathrm du$$

Comment: Since it is a sphere z and y are interchangable if I am consistent with them all correct?

Comment: @justanguy correct.  Because this is a sphere, you can interchange any variable, really.

Comment: Is r(z) suppose to be the radius?

Comment: @justanguy Yes.  $r(z)$ is the radius at a given height $z$.  That is, if you were 3 units from the ground, the radius at that point will be $r(3)$.  This isn't to be confused with the *overall* radius (e.g. If the problem said a sphere of radius $4$, then $R$ (big $R$) $=4$, but $r(z)$ is not always $4$).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Sketch a graph of the curve $y=\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$. It is the upper half of a circle centred at the origin with radius $R$. Now draw a vertical line that intersects the semicircle and shade the part of the circle that is to the right of this line and above the $x$-axis. Imagine rotating this shaded region about the $x$-axis. This will represent the (sideways) liquid in the (sideways) sphere. In order for it to have a (sideways) height of $h$, notice that the equation of the vertical line must be $x=R-h$. Hence, using the disk method, the volume will be given by:
$$
V = \int_{R-h}^R \pi y^2 dx = \int_{R-h}^R \pi \left(\sqrt{R^2-x^2}\right)^2 dx= \pi\int_{R-h}^R (R^2-x^2)~dx
$$

Comment: But all the water will fall out of your sphere... (We get the same result).

Comment: @RossMillikan Yeah hahah. I suppose we could have integrated with respect to $y$ instead, but I wanted the final integral to be in terms of $x$.

Comment: What could be the most *open-abstract* approach towards a question like this: `Assume that water is poured into a spherical bottle at a constant rate. How to draw the graph that represents the height of water in the bottle as a function of the amount of water in the bottle?` Can we simply say `h` is infact a function of `r` of the disk? where `r` increases with volume and then decreases while `h` continues to grow.

Answer (score 2):

Let the sphere be represented by $x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$.  The $x$ axis is vertical and we start filling it from the bottom, $x=-R$ (to follow your notation).  Think of chopping the filled volume into thin disks.  The disk at a given value of $x$ has a radius of $r(x)=\sqrt {R^2-x^2}$ and a thickness $dx$, so a volume $\pi r^2 dx=\pi(R^2-x^2)dx$  To get the whole volume, we then want $$\int_{-R}^{-R+h}\pi(R^2-x^2)dx$$
Note that your formula is missing limits and the $dx$ that tells us what to integrate with respect to.  You have probably heard that it is better to be able to figure this out than to memorize the formula.

Comment: I don't follow this at all, what is z^2 from?

Comment: I don't see $z^2$ anywhere except in the definition of the sphere.  That is the equation of a sphere of radius $R$ centered on the origin.  To get the volume, we add up slices parallel to the $yz$ plane (horizontal) of thickness $dx$ (vertical).

Comment: Why is x = -r? Should it be positive

Comment: Because I started filling the sphere from the bottom so the water won't fall out.  The sphere extends from $x=-R$ to $x=R$.  Note that $R$ and $r$ are different.  $R$ is the radius of the sphere.  $r(x)$ is the radius of the circular slice perpendicular to the $x$ axis at location $x$

Comment: I don't really understand that at all but I will just accept it.

Comment: Well what now? I have the integral, I get some indecipherable amount of varibles that doesn't equal the book answer of pi/3

Comment: If you have a text, this is under the volumes of revolution section, the disk method.  The area we are revolving is a piece of a circle.

Comment: This is not under that section but just the volume, revolution is next.

Comment: Then how do I get an answer? It appears h may be 1/4 of the entire sphere.

Comment: if h was 1/4 the total height does that do anything?

Comment: If you do the integral, you get $\pi Rh^2-\frac \pi 3 h^3$.  If $h=\frac R4$ then the volume is $\pi R^3(\frac 1{16}-\frac 1{192})=\frac {11}{192}\pi R^3$ or $\frac {11}{256} \approx 0.043$ of the sphere.

Comment: Oh nevermind teh answer is the first thing you got but I don't know why.

Comment: Why is R squared?

Comment: Please be more explicit in your questions.  Are you referring to the integrand in the original integral?  The radius of the slice at a given $x$ is $\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$

Comment: The very first formula in the top line has an R^2, why?

Comment: As I said, that is the formula for a sphere, centered on the origin, of a [sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere) of radius $R$.