# Volume of a shape

Tags: calculus

The base is the semicircle $$y=\sqrt{9−x^2},$$ where $x\in[-3;3]$. The cross sections perpendicular to the $x$-axis are squares.

Comment: Yes but it is wrong.

Comment: I really need help I can't do any of these, I injured my hand and can't type well and I have 8 hours of homewokr still.

Comment: What is exactly your question here? Can't draw? Can't imagine the whole shape? Can't find the integral? What?? :)

Comment: All of that. I keep asking questions and no one will answer.

Comment: I really need help I can't do any of these, I injured my hand and can't type well and I have 8 hours of homewokr still.

Answer (score 5):

The below plot shows what @Ross notes you. In fact you have to do the following integral $$V=\int_{-3}^3(\sqrt{9-x^2})^2dx$$

[image]

Comment: Why is it squared?

Comment: @justanguy: Ross told you exactly what you need. Please review his answer and comments again and reflect.

Comment: Ok but I don't understand it.

Comment: Why is it squared?

Comment: What is the area of a square?

Comment: Why a square is base is circle.

Comment: Your solid isn't actually a square. The base is a semicircle.

Comment: The only problem I have with this drawing is that the cross sections don't appear to be squares... maybe the z-axis isn't drawn to scale?

Comment: @TestSubject528491, the width is $dx$

Comment: @sidht yes I understand that, but the actual *cross sections* (which are two-dimensional by the way, not 3D solids) are supposed to be squares, as indicated in the OP's problem. What you're referring to are rectangular prism slices, and these are technically not cross sections. They're just representative examples of the cross sections. The representative example shown in the picture does have a width of $dx$, and the correct length of $\sqrt{9-x^2}$, however the height is not indicated and it doesn't appear to be the same as the length.

Comment: Nice answer +1!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  The idea, just like in [your other question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429481/volume-of-liquid-needed-to-fill-sphere-to-height-h) is to chop the shape up into volumes we can simply compute and add them up.  We can easily compute the volume of a cuboid.  If we know the base is a square with side $\sqrt {9-x^2}$ and height $dx$ the volume is what?  Now integrate from $-3$ to $3$

Comment: I don't even know that word, did you just make that up?

Comment: No, a [parallelepiped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelepiped) is a 3D analog of a parallelogram.  In this case it has square corners like a rectangle.  [Cuboid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboid) would have been a better term for that reason.  I will fix it.

Comment: How did it happen into that shape? What happened to the circle?

Comment: You said the cross section was square.  The circle just defines how big the squares are.

Comment: I don't understand what a cross section is then.

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: I don't understand. why from 3 t o-3

Comment: I don't understand what a cross section is then.

Comment: A cross section is the shape that results from slicing a solid.  In this case you are told that if you slice it with a plane perpendicular to the $x$ axis, you will get a square.  That would be similar to saying if you slice a sphere, you get a circle, if you slice a cube parallel to a face you get a square, if you slice a cube perpendicular to the body diagonal you get a hexagon.  You go from $-3$ to $3$ because that is the range in $x$.

Comment: But what if I slice it at x = 0? Howw do i know height|

Comment: For your shape, you put $x=0$ into the equation.  You get $y=3$, so the cross section is a $3 \times 3$ square.

Answer (score 1):

First, relax and take a deep breath. Panic is counterproductive. Second, realize that you *can* understand these problems. Thousands of students have, and so can you. Here's a walkthrough:

1. Can you envision what the base of your solid is? $y=\sqrt{9-x^2}$ describes a semicircle of radius 3, lying above the $x$-axis. Imagine this drawn on the floor, or actually get down and draw it on the floor. In the $x$ direction, it runs from $x=-3$ to $x=3$, as indicated in Babak's picture.
2. The problem says that the cross sections of the solid perpendicular to the $x$ axis are squares. Look down at the picture of the base and imagine that your solid is made up of many square cards, each of which has its bottom edge lying within your base (the semicircle). It may be hard to visualize what this pile of cards looks like exactly, but that's less important than the idea of an object made up of lots of vertical slices. If your hand isn't bothering you too much you can get some stiff paper and cut it into squares and prop them vertically on the floor.
3. Once you have the picture, the rest is more or less easy. For every $x$ value from $-3$ to $3$, what is the edge size of its associated square? Easy: it's just $\sqrt{9-x^2}$. Again, look at Babak's picture.
4. Now what will the area of each square be? You know that the side lying on the floor is of length $\sqrt{9-x^2}$, so the area will be $(\sqrt{9-x^2})^2 = 9-x^2$.
5. All that's left is to integrate all of these areas, from $x=-3$ to $x=3$. We'll then have the volume equal to
   $$
   \int_{-3}^39-x^2\;dx
   $$
   and I'll leave the rest for you to do.

Hope this helps. Just remember, you *can* do this.