# Water Level of a Spherical Container

Tags: geometry, functions

The task at hand is to define a function $f$, where $x$ represents the volume of water put into a spherical container of radius $R$, and $f(x)$ represents the depth of water measured from the deepest point.

Comment: What are your own thoughts?

Comment: Well I have solved a simpler two dimensional version of the problem involving a circle and area. What I did was define an angle theta whose rays intercepted where the water level ended on either side. I calculated the area of the triangle formed and subtracted said area from the sector of the circle formed by theta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fill a spherical tank up to height $h$, the required volume is;

$$V=\int_0^h\pi(R^2 - (z-R)^2)\;\mathrm dz$$

i.e given a value $x$ which represents volume just solve;

$$x =\int_0^h\pi(R^2 - (z-R)^2)\;\mathrm dz$$

and set $f(x) = h$.

Comment: My only question is what does $z$ represent.

Comment: Height. The sphere I took to still be with south-pole at $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: So $z$ and $h$ represent the same thing?

Comment: Here. Use this link. They even show you how to come up with the integral (calc II techniques). http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429481/volume-of-liquid-needed-to-fill-sphere-to-height-h